# TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid filter: 'comments_filter'

Tags: python, django

В приложении *profiles* создал папку *templatetags* в нее добавил файл init и файл с тегами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зарегал приложение в *settings.py*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В *base.html* подключил теги

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наследую *base.html* вызываю тег

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код в файле *comments_tree.py*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Забыли подключить `{% load comments_tree %}` в том шаблоне, в котором вы используете фильтр — base.html тут совсем ни при чём

Comment: Да это так, но как это работает я так и не понял! Если в base.html я уже подключил тег, почему мне нужно подключить его второй раз в конкретном шаблоне??? Как это вообще работает?